# How to read multiple payload from nfc tags and store the payloads into an arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nfc

Hi Stackers I still new in coding and need some help. Now I have two NFC tags and both tags is storing with different Geo coordinates(longitude, latitude). Currently, I able to read the payload from the NFC tags. What I want is to store the payloads from both of the NFC tags into an arraylist. When I read the first tag it does stored the payload into arraylist, but when read second tag the payload will overwritten the previous payload.

Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".arraylist"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:scheme="geo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (nfcAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "nfc not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
    if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.NFC_SETTINGS"));
        Toast.makeText(this, "nfc not yet open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),0 );


}

private void readIntent(Intent intent){
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    for(int i=0; i<parcelables.length; i ++){
        NdefMessage message =(NdefMessage)parcelables[i];
        NdefRecord[] records = message.getRecords();
        for(int j=0; j<records.length; j++){
            NdefRecord record = records[j];
            byte[] original = record.getPayload();
            byte[] value = Arrays.copyOfRange(original,0,original.length);
            String payload = new String(value);

            if(list != null){
                list.add(payload);
                System.out.println(list);
            }

        }
    }
}



@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    readIntent(intent);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}
```

Here is my output:
I/System.out: [geo:1.523534,103.633690]

But my expectation output is:
[geo:1.523534, 103.633690, geo:1.5364496, 103.656321]

So how can achieve that second tag payload will not overwritten the previous payload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem this time is that you are not creating a `new` instance of a Fragment like your were in your previous similar question, you are creating a `new` arraylist every time a card is read and thus de-referencing the first list object for it to be deleted by the garbage collection.

This is a classic variable initialisation issue.

`readIntent` is called every time a card is read.
So remove the first line of `readIntent where you create a new list.

e.g.

```java
private void readIntent(Intent intent){
    Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

....
```

Then in your class definition initialise the arraylist once only.

e.g.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You save my day! Thanks for answering my silly question i'm very appreciate that. Hope you have a nice day too.

Comment: No problem, if these were the correct answers that solved your problems then you should mark them as answered as well to show others that they were the correct answers and you can also vote them up to indicate that they were useful.